# Why is EF eagerly loading all navigation properties with EF Database first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use EF Database first, because I like to design my databases in SQL Management Studio, and it's quite frankly very easy to make Visual Studio create all the entities directly from the database, without having to do any code.

How ever, I noticed on SQL Profiler, that EF is eagerly loading all the related entities of an object, whenever I call ToList() on the result collection.

Let's say I have an entity like this:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SomeOtherEntity> ListOfOtherEntites { get; set; }
}
```

I could then have a query, getting a list of these entities:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> GetAllOfTheSomeEntities(Guid customerId){
   return dbContex.SomeEntity.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
}
```

At a later point in the code, I want to do stuff with this list (for instance in a controller in MVC), and I would call ToList() on the query:

```
var list = repository.GetAllOfTheSomeEntities(customerId).ToList();
```

Even though I never use the property "ListOfOtherEntites" on the Entity, it's still being loaded into my server's memory.

I know that I don't have to worry about this in Code first, because I can control the loading with the "virtual/non-virtual" properties and Include - but how am I to go about this in Database first?

I could alter my entities after I load them from the database; but they're just gonna get recreated if I update my model at a later point.

Comment: How do you know ListOfOtherEntites is loaded into memory ? As far as I know, it shouldn't be loaded until you try to get it (and then a query is sent to the database if you have proxycreationenabled, otherwise it will be null and you can't get the values out of it once the parent object is loaded into memory)

Comment: I can see that using the SQL Profiler, and by setting a breakpoint in my code, just after I call the ToList(). All the navigation properties are being pulled out from the database, right away.

Comment: You can turn the lazy loading off in EF and can use include keyword to load what you want to load.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Azhar. If you can post an answer showing where to do it, I will accept it for you. ( can find out where to do it, but I would like to give you the rep)

Comment: Obviously this is the opposite of Lazy Loading and I cannot see how turning off lazy loading can possibly solve this. @MichaelCleverly it may be beneficial to show the SQL that does the eager loading

Comment: Well, if I can turn off LazyLoading, I can just use Include whenever I need the navigation properties. I think that will do the trick for me.

Comment: What is the code for `repository.GetAllOfTheSomeEntities(id)`?

Comment: @pseudocoder It's in the example already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're experiencing issues with lazy loading then I might recommend turning lazy loading off within your EF context.

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

From here you can then include the related entities using LINQ's `.Include()` method like so:

```
var posts = context.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark your navigation properties as `virtual` to enable lazy loading in entity framework.

```
public class SomeEntity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<SomeOtherEntity> ListOfOtherEntites { get; set; }
}
```

Doesn't simply modifying the generated code fix the problem?

Comment: If you read the code, I'm aware of this solution. How ever, with database first, all my code changes in the entity models, will be overwritten as soon as i update my model from the database again.